# how to fetch require record from query mentioned

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

in given image i have attached my table schema,
i want to to fetch menuid against appropriate role.

```
Select MenuId from tblAccess where RoleId=1:2;
```

It should return 
MenuId 
2.03,
2.04 and
2.05
because these MenuId containing RoleId of 1 and 2

[image]

Please help me out to fecth MenuId against role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing your *history* here (Oracle Apex), and seeing `roleid = 1:2`, that looks like an Apex shuttle item or select list item which allows multiple selection. If that's so, then you'd have to split that colon-separated values into rows and use it as in this SQL*Plus example:

```
SQL> var p1_roleid varchar2(10);
SQL> exec :p1_roleid := '1:2';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> with tblaccess (menuid, roleid) as
  2    (select 2.03, 2 from dual union all
  3     select 2.04, 2 from dual union all
  4     select 2.05, 1 from dual union all
  5     select 2.06, 3 from dual
  6    )
  7  select menuid
  8  from tblaccess
  9  where roleid in (select regexp_substr(:P1_ROLEID, '[^:]+', 1, level)
 10                   from dual
 11                   connect by level <= regexp_count(:P1_ROLEID, ':') + 1
 12                  )
 13  order by menuid;

    MENUID
----------
      2,03
      2,04
      2,05

SQL>
```

---

In Apex, that would look like

```
select menuid
from tblaccess
where roleid in (select regexp_substr(:P1_ROLEID, '[^:]+', 1, level)
                 from dual
                 connect by level <= regexp_count(:P1_ROLEID, ':') + 1
                )
order by menuid;
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `in` condition

```
Select MenuId from tblAccess where RoleId in (1,2);
```